# React - Firebase - display single post

Tags: reactjs, firebase

Fairly new to Firebase. I have created one page that shows all posts like so:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { db } from "../firebase";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";

function Fire() {
  function useCourses() {
    const [courses, setCourses] = useState([]);

    useEffect(() => {
      const unsubscribe = db
        .collection("courses")
        .get()
        .then((snapshot) => {
          snapshot.forEach((doc) => {
            const newCourses = snapshot.docs.map((doc) => ({
              id: doc.id,
              ...doc.data(),
            }));

            setCourses(newCourses);
          });
        })
        .catch((e) => {
          console.log(e);
        });

      return () => unsubscribe();
    }, []);

    return courses;
  }

  const courses = useCourses();

  return (
    <div className="courses">
      <ul className="courses__list">
        {courses.map((course) => (
          <li
            className="course"
            key={course.id}
            style={{
              backgroundImage: `url(${course.image})`,
            }}
          >
            <h3>
              <Link to={`/courses/${course.id}`} className="course__title">
                {course.title}
              </Link>
            </h3>
          </li>
        ))}
      </ul>
    </div>
  );
}

export default Fire;
```

Then I have page just to show single post like so:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { db } from "../firebase";

function CourseDetail() {
  const [title, setTitle] = useState("");
  const [text, setText] = useState("");

  useEffect(() => {
    const single = db
      .collection("courses")
      .doc("329ddd70-c9bd-11ea-a9d4-39439f5f6cce");

    single
      .get()
      .then(function (doc) {
        if (doc.exists) {
          let { title, main_text } = doc.data();
          setTitle(title);
          setText(main_text);
        }
      })
      .catch(function (error) {
        console.log("Error getting document:", error);
      });
  }, []);

  return (
    <div>
      <h3>{title}</h3>
      <p>{text}</p>
    </div>
  );
}

export default CourseDetail;
```

When i put specific id into .doc() it works fine. My question is how do I pass id from `Link` to display data from specific post (router and links working fine). Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are correctly sending the id of the post in the Link

```js
<Link to={`/courses/${course.id}`} >
```

In the component used to show a single post you can retrieve this id using `useParams`

```js
import { useParams } from "react-router-dom";
const { courseId } = useParams();
```

Also in your routes, you should configure the path to accept courseId

```js
 <Route path="/courses/:courseId"  component={CourseDetail} />
```

Comment: Did all that but still not working. When I console.log courseId I get the correct number.  Do I put anything inside .doc() ?

Comment: Yes. The courseId should be used to fetch the document ````const single = db.collection("courses").doc(courseId);````

Comment: I thought so. Still no luck.

Comment: Is there any error ? Are you getting any error in console as we have a console.log statement inside catch. Also add an else block to ````if(document.exists)```` so that we can see if it is because document is not existing

Comment: Your solution was correct. I made mistake when passing wrong id. It works now. Thanks for help